# Can't move my div using float-right inside container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a container where i store 2 div's. ".logo" and ".navbar-list" how can I move my ".navbar-list" to the right edge of container.

Previously everything worked but when I switched bootstrap to version 4.3.1 my div's overlapped .I've tried float:right but is not working.

```css
container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 380px;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar-list {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/640px-HSV-Logo.png" /></a>
    <h1>WITAJ W <span>DOMU!</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-list ">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sklep
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md ">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Zaloguj się
                                </button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably something overwrite your style try to use `float: right !important;`

Comment: Floats are usually the last resort, embrace the [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/) and [Layout Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/utilities-for-layout/) dude and quit repeating yourself with unnecessary additional css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of methods of achieving your desired result! In my opinion, Flexbox would be your best option. You should add `display: flex` to your `.container`. You can add the `flex` to the `.logo` container as well, if you want the logo and h1 to sit side by side.

You should also avoid using `float`, as this often makes HTML behave unexpectedly. You can replace this with `justify-content: space-between`.

I've amended your example above to incorporate my amends:

```css
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 380px;
  /*margin-right: 0; */
  /*position: absolute; */
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-list {
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/640px-HSV-Logo.png" /></a>
    <h1>WITAJ W <span>DOMU!</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-list ">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sklep
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md ">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Zaloguj się
                                </button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a high level, the go-to method for this situation is using flexbox instead of floats. Not sure about Bootstrap in your case or why you had that change happen.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end; /* and many more positioning options */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `float: right;` to your `.navbar-list` css then you can move your div to right side

```
 .navbar-list {
   color: white;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100%;
   float: right;
}
```